# Multiprocessing python - most processes are idle after completing its process

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-multiprocessing

I am using python multiprocess module to parallelise my function. I have a grouped data frame and am sending one group at a time to pool.imap like this - `mypool.imap(my_func,(group for name, group in gpd))` . Though everything works fine, after some time only one process is running for long time. I don't know how to understand this, can anyone help to understand why this is happening. How data is sent to each process? One group to one process? Is it because that particular process has to process a big group? Why it is not sharing with other process when the other processes are idle?

[image]

Comment: If your tasks are different in size, then a plausible explanation is that some tasks take longer to complete. At some point there is only one left running.  Your pool processes do not communicate with each other and automagically "share" work from others.  Without seeing your code it is impossible to advise more than this.

Comment: What do you mean by tasks in different size? Every process is running the same function. So it should be same right?  Sorry if my understanding is wrong here

Comment: It depends on what your function does.  In some cases, a function can run a very short or a very long time based on difference in parameters. Some functions depend on outside data or random events before they complete. If you believe your function should not have any variance in running time, then we need to see your code before we can try to help any further.